# strncat в цикле

Tags: c++, visual-studio, char, data-structures

Нужно решить задачу: "Ввести с клавиатуры строку и вывести новую, которая будет такой же, но предварительно удалив все 'b', но только перед которой стоит 'c'". Например ввод: "aabbcbaacbba". вывод новой строки: "aabbcaacba". Я понимаю, что просто в цикле проходимся по строке и проверяем, если символ **b** , а предыдущий - **c**, то ничего не делаем, в противном случае добавляем в новую строку символ. Но вот как добавлять их туда я не понимаю, фатальные ошибки выдаёт непонятные. ***Решить нужно используя именно символьный тип данных***.

Вот мой код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");

    char s[255];
    char result[255];
    char temp[8];

    cout << "Введите строкy" << endl;
    cin.getline(s, 255);
    
    cout << "исходная строка : " << s << endl;
    

    for (int i = 1; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == 'b' && s[i - 1] == 'c')
        {
            cout << i << " === " << endl;
            //continue;
        }
        else
        {
            temp[10] = s[i];
            strncat_s(result, 25, temp, 10);
        }
    }
    cout << "исходная строка : " << s << endl;
    cout << result << endl;

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

1. а это вы ловко делаете!!!

   ```
    char temp[8];
    ...
            temp[10] = s[i];
   ```
2. и еще касательно вашего кода - чтобы работать со строкой `result` функциями `strxxx`, то надо из `result` предварительно сделать хотя бы пустую строку, т.е.

   ```
    result[0] = 0;
   ```

а то без этого очень много чего нехорошего может произойти (да у вас и происходит)

**P.S.**

почему вас не устраивает посимвольный анализ - если символ строки 1 удовлетворяет критериям, он переносится в новую строку, если не удовлетворяет - не переносится?

Comment: Почему не устраивает? я ж вроде написал, что в через цикл надо делать и проверять каждый символ. Но спасибо за  result[0] = 0;

Answer (score 1):

Вот рабочий код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");

    char string[255];
    char newString[255];
    
    int newStringCurrentIndex = 1;

    cout << "Введите строкy: " << endl;
    cin.getline(string, 255);
    
    cout << "Исходная строка: " << string << endl;
    
    char currentChar;
    char previousChar = string[0];
    
    newString[0] = string[0];
    
    for (int i = 1; i < strlen(string); i++)
    {
        currentChar = string[i];
        
        if (currentChar == 'b') {
            
            if (previousChar != 'c') {
                newString[newStringCurrentIndex] = string[i]; // b
                newStringCurrentIndex++;
            }
        }
        else {
            newString[newStringCurrentIndex] = string[i]; // не b
            newStringCurrentIndex++;
        }
        
        previousChar = currentChar;
    }
    
    cout << "Новая строка: " << newString << endl;

}
```

Comment: Работает, только в новой строке содержатся пустые элементы и исходная строка 

Введите строкy:
aaaacbaaabaaaacb
Исходная строка: aaaacbaaabaaaacb
Новая строка: aaaacaaabaaaacММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММaaaacbaaabaaaacb

Comment: @Alex эта ошибка только у вас видимо. У меня работает правильно. Исходная строка: aaaacbaaabaaaacb                                                                                                              
Новая строка: aaaacaaabaaaac

Comment: @Alex я проверял работу этого кода здесь https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler